# Postgresql: Help calculating delta value in Postgres while using group by function

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by, timescaledb

I am building a stockmarket database. I have one table  with timestamp, symbol, price and volume. The volume is cumulative volume traded per day. for e.g.

```
|         timestamp          | symbol |  price   | volume |
|----------------------------|--------|----------|--------|
| 2022-06-11 12:42:04.912+00 | SBIN   | 120.0000 |      5 |
| 2022-06-11 12:42:25.806+00 | SBIN   | 123.0000 |      6 |
| 2022-06-11 12:42:38.993+00 | SBIN   | 123.4500 |      8 |
| 2022-06-11 12:42:42.735+00 | SBIN   | 108.0000 |     12 |
| 2022-06-11 12:42:45.801+00 | SBIN   | 121.0000 |     14 |
| 2022-06-11 12:43:43.186+00 | SBIN   | 122.0000 |     16 |
| 2022-06-11 12:43:45.599+00 | SBIN   | 125.0000 |     17 |
| 2022-06-11 12:43:51.655+00 | SBIN   | 141.0000 |     20 |
| 2022-06-11 12:43:54.151+00 | SBIN   | 111.0000 |     24 |
| 2022-06-11 12:44:01.908+00 | SBIN   | 123.0000 |     27 |
```

I want to query to get OHLCV (open high low close and volume) data. I am using the following to get OHLC data but not volume and i am getting proper OHLC. Note that i am using timescale db timebucket function similar to date_trunc

```
SELECT
time_bucket('1 minute', "timestamp") AS time,
symbol,
max(price) AS high,
first(price, timestamp) AS open,
last(price, timestamp) AS close,
min(price) AS low,
FROM candle_ticks
GROUP BY time, symbol
ORDER BY time DESC, symbol;
```

So for volume, I need to calculate the difference of  max / last volume in the same time and max/last volume in the previous time frame.  to get the following data

```
|          time          | symbol |   high   |   open   |  close   |   low    | volume |
|------------------------|--------|----------|----------|----------|----------|--------|
| 2022-06-11 12:44:00+00 | SBIN   | 123.0000 | 123.0000 | 123.0000 | 123.0000 |   14   |
| 2022-06-11 12:43:00+00 | SBIN   | 141.0000 | 122.0000 | 111.0000 | 111.0000 |   10   |
| 2022-06-11 12:42:00+00 | SBIN   | 123.4500 | 120.0000 | 121.0000 | 108.0000 |    3   |
```

What should be sql be like? I tried to use lag, but lag and group buy together is not playing well..

Comment: Since you're using TimescaleDB, we recently opened a GitHub issue to discuss a new hyperfunction that would be helpful for OCHLV datasets. If you have any additional thoughts or input, please share!

https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/issues/445

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you put your query in a CTE?

```
with ivals as (
  SELECT time_bucket('1 minute', "timestamp") AS time,
         symbol,
         max(price) AS high,
         first(price, timestamp) AS open,
         last(price, timestamp) AS close,
         min(price) AS low,
         max(volume) AS close_volume
    FROM candle_ticks
   GROUP BY time, symbol
)
select i.*,
       close_volume - coalesce(
                        lag(close_volume) 
                          over (partition by symbol, time::date
                                    order by time),
                        0 
                      ) as time_volume
  from ivals i
;
```

Comment: +1 It works beautifully, but when i tried to build a continuous aggregate view, I get the error - Window functions are not supported by continuous aggregates. any alternative suggestions?

Comment: @ArvindS.A  I'm sorry that I do not have much experience with TimescaleDB.  I added the TimescaleDB tag to your question as I think they have a team that answers questions on SO.

Comment: I think, in this case, you can apply the window function over your caggs and keep your continuous aggregated view a bit simpler/raw. I'd also encourage you to open a feature request in the timescaledb issues, so more people can upvote and the team can prioritize it as a feature.

Maybe this  [blog](https://www.timescale.com/blog/rethinking-the-database-materialized-view-as-an-index/) can help you to understand the mindset.

Comment: It's unlikely we'll ever be able to do window functions inside of continuous aggregates ( due to how they interact with invalidation), however, we might be able to apply the window functions for you after the aggregation is calculated (which is when window functions are applied anyway). But either running the window query separately or in a separate view on top of the cagg should be a good option for you.

Comment: To be very clear: what that would mean is that the `ivals` CTE becomes your continuous agg, and then you just run the rest of the query referring to the continuous aggregate. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Mike Organek's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72586282/878272) answer, you can collect the data into buckets via CTE and then in your main query, subtract a minute from the `time` column to get the `time` value for the previous bucket. You can use that value to
`LEFT JOIN` the row for the previous time bucket within the same day:

```sql
WITH buckets as (

SELECT
  time_bucket('1 minute', "timestamp") AS time,
  symbol,
  max(price) AS high,
  first(price, timestamp) AS open,
  last(price, timestamp) AS close,
  min(price) AS low,
  max(volume) AS close_volume
FROM candle_ticks
GROUP BY time, symbol
ORDER BY time DESC, symbol
)

SELECT
  b.*,
  coalesce(b.close_volume - b2.close_volume,0) time_volume

FROM
  buckets b
  LEFT JOIN buckets b2 ON (b.time::date = b2.time::date and b.time - interval '1 minute' = b2.time)
```

This method will avoid the restrictions that TimescaleDB places on window functions.

Comment: Sigh. Had thought that using a lateral join would work with c-aggs since they don't allow CTE's and the lateral query is super simple. However the qwuery lateral form would not be allowed since the grouping is done in the sub-selects, and the c-agg itself requires a group by. I think we'll just end up calculating the diff outside of the query :-(